# pythonにおける配列の座標指定

Tags: opencv, python3, numpy

python3.6 opencv3
numpy ndarray中のある一つの位置(x,y)座標のようなものを求める方法がわかりません。
numpy ndarrayのアドレスにアクセスしたい理由は、cv2.Keypoints()の引数に行列の行x,列yがあり，アドレスを使わないと引数が‌​得られないのではと考えたためです。

```
patches[x]=
[[[255 255 255]
[255 255 255]
[255 255 255]]
```

上記のような配列の真ん中の255の位置をある変数に指定するにはどうすればよいのでしょか？

配列a=[255 255 255]  
     　　　 [255 255 255]
      　　　 [255 255 255]
の行1列1のアドレスをbに代入b=&a[1][1]をpythonで実現したいです.
単に生のアドレスを変数に獲得したいというのが目的です

Comment: カッコの対応が合ってない気がします。

Comment: 真ん中とはどの部分ですか？ `[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]` だったとしたらどの部分でしょう。

Comment: 「ある変数に指定」とは、配列の要素を別の値に書き換えたいということでしょうか？　たとえばある場所の255を0にしたい、など。

Comment: [1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]なら5を真ん中としてます

Comment: 3×3の配列a=[[1,2,3] [4,5,6] [7,8,9]]なら5の位置を変数に指定したい、つまりC++ならポインターのようなことをpythonでするにはどうしたらいいのかわからなくて質問させていただきました

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/88588

Comment: @user24713 質問を編集して、行いたいことを C++ など他の言語で書いた場合どうなるかを追記してくださいませんか？

Comment: C++が間違ってたらすいません

Comment: @user24713 [回答に対するコメント](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/37268/python%E3%81%AB%E3%81%8A%E3%81%91%E3%82%8B%E9%85%8D%E5%88%97%E3%81%AE%E5%BA%A7%E6%A8%99%E6%8C%87%E5%AE%9A#comment37380_37282)で、行列の特定の要素のアドレスを取得したい、と書かれていますが、その目的は何ですか？　単に生のアドレスが欲しいだけなのか、参照渡しのように後からその場所の値を書き換えたいのか、よく分かりませんでした。質問に追記して頂ければと思います。

Answer (score 1):

真ん中の位置にある値を取得したい、ということでよろしいでしょうか。
提示されたコードは開始括弧が多く、3次配列なのか2次配列なのか判断できませんでした。
C++で`&a[1][1]`だということなので、2次配列と解釈します。

```py
import numpy

patches = numpy.array([
  [255, 255, 255],
  [255, 255, 255],
  [255, 255, 255]
  ])

print( patches[1,1] )
#=> 255

patches[1,1] = 100
print(patches)
#=> [[255 255 255]
#    [255 100 255]
#    [255 255 255]]
```

ndarrayは各次元のインデックスをまとめて指定できます。
指定しなかった場合は、指定しなかった全てが選択された新しいndarrayになります。

```py
print( patches[1] )
#=> [255 100 255]
```

追記：C言語などにあるようなメモリアドレスはnumpyの抽象化によってアクセスできません。

Comment: すいません。質問が分かりにくくなってしまいました。聞きたかったのは、3×3行列のaの行1列1の要素の値ではなく、そのアド‌​レス(位置position)を取得したい‌​という質問でした

Comment: Pythonは参照渡しできません。その為、アドレスは通常アクセス出来ないかと思います。

Comment: そうでしたか。ご回答ありがとうございました

Comment: point.ptというように使う ptっていうモジュールは使えませんか？

Comment: 言語レベルで配列のメモリアドレスとの関連付けが定義されているわけではなかったと思います。また、numpyのndarrayが必ずしも連続したデータとしてメモリに記録されているわけではないことも踏まえると、アドレスを取得することの意味があるか疑問があります。アドレスを取得したい理由は何でしょうか？

Comment: [2つ前の私の回答](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/37268/python%E3%81%AB%E3%81%8A%E3%81%91%E3%82%8B%E9%85%8D%E5%88%97%E3%81%AE%E5%BA%A7%E6%A8%99%E6%8C%87%E5%AE%9A#comment37381_37282)で参照渡しできないと記述しましたが、よく考えたら逆です。オブジェクトを参照渡ししかできないので、Python内で閉じたプログラムであればアドレスにアクセスする必要がないということです。

Comment: アドレスにアクセスしたい理由は、cv2.Keypoints()の引数に行列の行x,列yがあり，アドレスを使わないと引数が得られないのではと考えたためです。

Comment: 誤解を避けるためにも、質問文にその説明を加えて下さい。

Comment: 了解いたしました。質問に不備があり申し訳ございません